# Application id in the blackberry push notification is expired

Tags: blackberry, push

For push notification in blackberry, i got application id from rim. It will valid only 4 months. For getting permanent application id what i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to contact the person who gave you the push credentials. And request them to upgrade your EVAL credentials to Production push credentials.

Comment: Thank you Rihan. But i need to implement push notification in my application. so i need to get permanent application id or Is their any other solution to provide push notification for a long period.

Comment: Eval credentials are meant to be used for testing purposes. Before you release your app, you have to change the credentials to production credentials. If you need to do more testing on Eval credentials, you could ask the contact at RIM and they should be able to extend it for you.

Comment: After testing push notification on eval urls and requesting new appId for production . Is There a change from evaluation urls and production Urls in my code while changing from eval mode to production mode .

Comment: @ahmedShoeib yes you will need to change url and appid for production

Comment: change the values to what's provided to you by RIM. If you haven't got it, please contact them